# How can I change docker image configurations?

Tags: docker

I'd like to change some configuration in a docker image. As I inspect it I see:

```
"ExposedPorts": {
            "49999/tcp": {},
            "50000/tcp": {},
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Env": [
             ...
            "JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT=50000",
             ...
        ],
```

What I'd like to do is to create a new image removing ExposedPorts 50000 and changing the JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT variable.

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another image by doing some changes and then a `docker commit` but the recommended way is to modify your Dockerfile and build a new image. If you do not have a Dockerfile for your image, you can create one with dockerfile-from-image from centurylinklabs.com

Comment: I've tried this dockerfile-from-image and it gives me a docker file. I can see the line where I can change the configuration I want, but I also see some lines that add or copy files that I probably don't have, like this (at the beginning): `ADD file:5f0fca122586fe4ea79c5f22acef96c38632a6ce28da26dcc10aac32767cfeff in / ` . Anyway I think I can simply create a new docker file and make it start from the previous image, and then override the env variables. But how can I remove a port exposure?

Comment: you remove lines such as `EXPOSE 1234`